# SQL query for finding finished records published for different time periods

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

So imagine there is a blog and the owner can publishe his posts for different time periods, for example:

- 1 week
- 2 weeks
- 1 months
- 2 months
- 6 months

after which the post should be deleted.

The time period is set in the column named, well , `time_period`, with integer value in it with `0` standing for 1 week, `1` standing for 2 weeks and etc

The date of creation is set in `created_at` column.

And so I need to write a sql query to fetch all the records that have expired publication date and there are 2 ways I can see to solve this problem:

1) Write a query with a lot of conditions like:

```
.where("(time_period = 0 AND created_at <= :one_week_ago) OR
        (time_period = 1 AND created_at <= :two_weeks_ago)",
         one_week_ago: Time.now - 1.week, 
         two_weeks_ago: Time.now - 2.weeks)
```

but for all the conditions

2) Or simply fetch all the records (with `find_each` method) and check each one for meeting the requirements

and I will probably go with the second one but I just wonder if there's an efficient way to write a query for this kind of situation ? Maybe some database functions or something like that?

Comment: Things would be easier if you just store the number of weeks in that column  (i.e. "4" for "1 month" and "8" for two months and so on). Then you could do `created_at <= current_date - interval '1 week' * time_period`

Comment: yeah, I should've thought about it. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i was doing this then i would, for my own sanity, add a date/datetime field to store the actual expiry time, which you can simply compare with the current time to see if a post has expired.  This would be set from the time_period option in a before_save callback.

```
class Post

  before_save :set_expiry_date

  def set_expiry_date
    self.expiry_date = self.calculate_expiry_date
  end

  def calculate_expiry_date
    #logic which takes time_period and multiplies it by weeks or whatever you do
  end
```

Now you can just look in the database and see which posts have expired.  Keep it simple.

Comment: I didnt even think about it for some reason -_- Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name. However if that is not an option you might be able to do something like:

```
where created_at <= case time_period when 0 then :one_week_ago
                                     when 1 then :two_weeks_ago
                                     ...
                    end
```